# command number in bash changes after login

Tags: bash, command-history, prompt

I want to display the command number in the bash terminal. By using `\!` I can get only get the command number after opening the shell. I want to continue that even after quitting shell.
For example:-
If I open a new shell, something like this appears `username@hostname`
But I want to get the number of commands I had typed from starting of the history like `875 username@hostname` where `875` is the number of commands I have typed.
From `\!` I am getting something like `2 username@hostname` where 2 is the number of commands I had typed after opening a shell

Comment: Saving it to a file would be an issue?

Comment: I guess yes, as it is going to take space after some time. Also managing those files can be a mess

Comment: Have you set `HISTFILE` to anything and is `HISTSIZE` set to some number?

Comment: Yes, I had set them to 1000000 as I want to store all the history.

Comment: Finally I was able to achieve this. Should I post it here or post it as answer to my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `history | wc -l`, I get the required result. So I made a function in `.bashrc` calling this and add it to PS1. It may not be the best possible solution, but for the time being, it gets my things done.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are not aware of the other number; "PROMPTING" in man bash says:

```
\!     the history number of this command
\#     the command number of this command
```

`history -c` resets history number `\!` to 1.

`bash` (=new shell) resets command number `\#` to 1.

Comment: I am aware of these things. But they are of not useful for my use-case as they always reset the history number/command number to 1 which I didn't want. Please let me know about any confusion/details required.